# In Scala how do I represent a mix of things and groups of things in a parameter list? X = (X | atom)*

Tags: scala

I have a `*`-parameter method. I would like to be able to pass a mix of atoms and groups
of atoms into the method. Ideally I would like the groups to be able to hold groups too.

The grammar rule would be:

```
X = (X | atom)*
```

The groups need to ordered, but not necessarily of class List.

The motivation is that there are many calls to the `*`-parameter method and some groups of parameters occur more than once amongst these calls. I would like to be able to store these groups in vals to re-use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
trait GroupOrAtom // or any other nicer name!
class Atom extends GroupOrAtom
class AtomGroup(val atoms: Seq[Atom]) extends GroupOrAtom

def process(elements: GroupOrAtom*) = ...
```

If you're looking for a more fancy way to do it using union types, try reading [Miles Sabin's amazing post on how to implement union types in Scala](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/). This should probably not be your first choice, though, as a solution implementing a common trait like `GroupOrAtom` is clearer and easier.

Comment: You can make the trait sealed to get extra checks for pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Could just passing tuples work for you?

```
def processor(tokens: Any) = // pattern match on tuples

processor('atom)
processor('atom1, 'atom2)
processor('atom1, ('atom2a, 'atom2b))
```